# Each child in a list should have a unique key - react error

Tags: reactjs

**EDIT, SOLVED:** Its because the outer div needs the key set on it. The most parent element must have the key set.

Each div should have a unique key as I am using the shortid library to generate one, bit lost here?!

Error:

backend.js:6 Warning: Each child in a list should have a unique "key" prop.
Check the render method of `JsonFeed`. See htt......-warning-keys for more information. in div (created by JsonFeed) in JsonFeed.

Render Function:

```
  // Renders to the browser
  public render(): React.ReactElement<IJsonFeedProps> {

    // Grabbing objects to use from state
    const { posts, isLoading} = this.state;
    const { postCount } = this.props;

    return (
      <div className={ styles.jsonFeed }>
        <div className={ styles.container }>
          <p className={ styles.title }>{ escape(this.props.description)}</p>
            <div className={ styles.containerDiv } > 
              {!isLoading ? (
                posts.slice(0, postCount).map(post => {
                  // Variables to use
                  let { id, name, url, imgUrl, endDate, startDate } = post;
                  // Return render of posts
                  return (
                    <div>
                      <div key={shortid.generate()} className={ styles.post }>
                        <Link href={ url } className={ styles.postLink } target="_blank">
                          {imgUrl !== 'undefined' &&
                            <div className={ styles.postImageContainer }><img className={ styles.postImage } src={ imgUrl } /></div>
                          }
                          <div className={ styles.postInfo }>
                            <p className={ styles.postName }>
                                { name.length < 40 ? name : name.substring(0, 40).trim() + '...' }
                            </p>
                            {startDate !== 'undefined' &&
                              <p className={ styles.postDate }><Moment format="DD/MM/YYYY">{ startDate }</Moment> - <Moment format="DD/MM/YYYY">{ endDate }</Moment></p>
                            }
                          </div>
                        </Link>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  );
                })
                ) : ( <Spinner className={ styles.postSpinner } label={'Loading...'} /> )
              }
              { !isLoading && posts.length == 0 || postCount == null ? <p className={ styles.postSorry }>Sorry, no posts are available.</p> : null }
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
    );
  }
```

Comment: Outer most div or parent div should have key..  <div key={shortid}>
                      <div key={shortid.generate()} className={ styles.post }>

Comment: Be cautious with what appears to be randomly generated keys, react uses these to reconcile its virtualDOM (i.e. what it needs to rerender). If keys change between renders but the components really *didn't* change, you will have unnecessary renders. Preferably you want your keys to be unique, *and consistent* to the component being rendered.

Comment: Ok if this gives me problems I will stop using it thanks man!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to assign a unique key to each post that you are mapping to components. E.g.:
`<div id={id}>`

```
 // Renders to the browser
  public render(): React.ReactElement<IJsonFeedProps> {

    // Grabbing objects to use from state
    const { posts, isLoading, errors } = this.state;
    const { postCount } = this.props;

    // If their is any errors, return an error message instead
    // if (errors) {
    //   return <p>{errors.message}</p>;
    // }

    return (
      <div className={ styles.jsonFeed }>
        <div className={ styles.container }>
          <p className={ styles.title }>{ escape(this.props.description)}</p>
            <div className={ styles.containerDiv } > 
              {!isLoading ? (
                posts.slice(0, postCount).map(post => {
                  // Variables to use
                  let { id, name, url, imgUrl, endDate, startDate } = post;
                  // Return render of posts
                  return (
                    <div key={id}>
                      <div key={shortid.generate()} className={ styles.post }>
                        <Link href={ url } className={ styles.postLink } target="_blank">
                          {imgUrl !== 'undefined' &&
                            <div className={ styles.postImageContainer }><img className={ styles.postImage } src={ imgUrl } /></div>
                          }
                          <div className={ styles.postInfo }>
                            <p className={ styles.postName }>
                                { name.length < 40 ? name : name.substring(0, 40).trim() + '...' }
                            </p>
                            {startDate !== 'undefined' &&
                              <p className={ styles.postDate }><Moment format="DD/MM/YYYY">{ startDate }</Moment> - <Moment format="DD/MM/YYYY">{ endDate }</Moment></p>
                            }
                          </div>
                        </Link>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  );
                })
                ) : ( <Spinner className={ styles.postSpinner } label={'Loading...'} /> )
              }
              { !isLoading && posts.length == 0 || postCount == null ? <p className={ styles.postSorry }>Sorry, no posts are available.</p> : null }
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
    );
  }
```

Comment: I forgot I added a <div> </div> just for flex box purposes around my main post elements. I have since moved the key={shortid.generate()} attribute onto the <div> and no errors no more :)

Comment: key, yes not id...edited. Yeah, you can generate an id as well, just make sure they are unique.